# Ruby on rails:undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm trying to learn Ruby on rails through this tutorial:http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/building-a-forum-from-scratch-with-ruby-on-rails/
I'm on step 8 but got an error:undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass. this error is around 
current_user.id. i'm using rails 4 and i I think the turoriels is for an older version , may be this is why i got this error. Can someone help me? sorry for my english.
this is the portion of code in my controller where the issue is.

```
@topic = Topic.new(params[:topic])
if @topic.save..
  @topic = Topic.new(:name => params[:topic][:name], :last_poster_id => current_user.id, :last_post_at => Time.now, :forum_id => params[:topic][:forum_id])
  if @post.save..
    flash[:notice] = "topic créé avec succès."  
    redirect_to "/forums/#{@topic.forum_id}"
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code sample. Also, do you know where `current_user` is defined? That's probably the issue.

Comment: You should also identify the specific line causing the error, which should involve an invocation of the `id` method on some object.

Comment: @mbratch I don't know where current_user is defined.i thought it is a rails's native method. should i define it? Can you please tell me where is the syntax error in my code Sample?

Comment: @topic = Topic.new(:name => params[:topic][:name], :last_poster_id => current_user.id, :last_post_at => Time.now, :forum_id => params[:topic][:forum_id])

this is the line causing the error

Comment: For example, `if @post.save..` is a syntax error. What are the trailing two periods for?

Comment: Use `@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]`

Answer (score 0):

The only possible place in your code as shown that could produce that warning is `current_user.id`. `current_user` must be nil.

Comment: i put this in my controller to define current_user
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
is that the good way to fix the problem?

Comment: actually i got this error
Couldn't find User without an ID

 @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])

Comment: That means session is not giving you back a user_id. I don't know enough about your setup to resolve that, and it's outside the scope of the original question anyway.

Comment: Use `@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't set the `session[:user_id]`.
Try this to set it with something like:

```
MyApp::MyApp.helpers do
  def current_user=(user)
    session[:user_id] = user ? user.id : nil
  end

  def current_user do
    User.find(session[:user_id]) rescue false
  end
end


MyApp.controllers :session do

  # to create a new session
  #
  # @param email [String]
  # @param password [String]
  post :login do
    user = User.find(email: params[:email])
    if user.password == params[:password].encrypt!
      current_user = user
    else
      error 401, 'Wrong email/password.'
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Use `@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]`